# C# pass a method as a parameter without specifying a method signature

Tags: c#

My goal is to be able to pass in a a method as a parameter just like a call back in javascript, But without specifying it's return value, or its function signature.

For example in javascript I could do:

```
function test(fn()){
fn();
}
```

fn() in JavaScript can be interpreted to any function type:

- function [return value] test(){}
- function [void] test(){}
- function [...] (arg1,arg2...){}

(function arguments overloading is possible...)

C# isn't offering me much with "Action" and "Func".

In C# I can create a delegate and then specify which type of a delegate it is:

- Action: a delegate to a function that returns void, all functions that the Action will point to, have to contain the same exact signature (not cool...)
- Func: a delegate to a function that returns a value, all functions that the Func will point to, have to contain the same exact signature (not cool...)

Using an Object will bring me to an expensive boxing/unboxing story, which I would like to avoid.

C# experts, talk to me..

Comment: I guess the answer is "C# is not JavaScript" -- C# is not a dynamically typed scripting language so don't try to use it as one.

Comment: _Using an Object will bring me to an expensive boxing/unboxing story_
: false. Using an Object will maybe force you to cast the object to something more specific. casting and boxing are two completely different subjects

Comment: What's the problem that you are trying to solve? I mean, once you get the delegate inside your method, how are you planning to call it?

Comment: Also, if you want to not pass in the function signature, how do you expect to call `fn()`? E.g. I could pass in the function `void f(int, int, bool, string)`. Did you mean you want to keep _just_ the return value unspecified?

Comment: Keeping the return value and the function signature unspecified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your only real option is object function(object[]){} but as you say there are huge issues with interpreting the object actual type.  C# is a strongly typed language unlike javascript and so the capabilities that you want are just not possible, and if they are then they shouldn't be used because you'll lose all of the advantages of using a strongly typed language in the first place.

Comment: I'm starting to get the feeling that this is the only option

Comment: @USS-Montana yeah, it's really trying to do something that C# wasn't designed to do, so you'd have to use a sledgehammer approach, hence objects as everything derives from them.  If you think this is the way to go, can you accept this as the answer?

Comment: Would like to wait a bit, maybe some one with a new approach will fascinate us, if not, I will accept.

Answer (score 4):

You call it "not cool", I call it "type safe"....

One solution might be the way you call the method. When this is the method you want to call:

```
public void Test(Action fn)
{
    fn();
}
```

And this is the one you want to pass:

```
public string MethodWithReturnType()
{
    return "Hello World!";
}
```

Then you can call `Test` with `MethodWithReturnType` by using a lambda:

```
Test(() => MethodWithReturnType());
```

Comment: But, by using Action you're specifying the signature and the return value.